# Nest Model save without parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models, uploadify

At the moment I have 2 models, Gallery and GalleryImage.

I am implementing uploadify into my Gallery insert page, so I batch upload images.

The problem is, that each GalleryImage has a gallery_id for the association.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way that I can save the GalleryImages before the user has actually saved the Gallery model?

IE User Clicks to create new Gallery -> Types Gallery Name -> Clicks select files -> Files start uploading -> User saves gallery. Problem being, the Photos cannot upload as they are missing the Gallery ID because the Gallery Model has not yet been saved.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Because you use uploadify, you must create the gallery before creating the photos.

Otherwise use a standard form with accepts_nested_attributes.

A work around could be to automatically create a temp gallery, insert all photos in it. And on form save switch all photos from temp to the newly created gallery.

As a sidenote, I recommend you use http://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload instead of Uploadify, I wrote a tutorial in their wiki.